# Xpages JavaBean static Notes Object cause error saving

Tags: xpages, javabeans, lotus-domino

In this JavaBean, I wrote some object as (static). But when I reach the logDoc.save() method, it returns error. Removing all (static), all run fine.
The error in console was:

```
HTTP JVM: lotus.domino.local.Document method: save, row: -1: 
NotesException: Notes error: You are not authorized to perform that operation
```

or

```
HTTP JVM:lotus.domino.local.NotesBase method: CheckObject, row: -1: 
NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled
```

depending on ACL settings for Anonymous.

Anyone can explain me whot's the problem with static objects here?

```
    public class AnyRest extends CustomServiceBean implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3548995909847938225L;

    private (static) Database logDB=null;
    private (static) Document logDoc=null;
    private (static) RichTextItem logBody=null;

    private  (static) void log(String text) {
        if (logDB==null) logDB= ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
        try {
            if (logDoc==null) {
                logDoc=logDB.createDocument();
                logDoc.replaceItemValue("form","log");
                logBody=logDoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
            }
            logBody.appendText(text);
            logBody.addNewLine();
            logDoc.save();
        } catch(NotesException ne) {
            logStackTrace(ne);
        }
    }


    private (static) void destroyLog() {

        try {
            if (logDoc!=null) {
                logDoc.save();
                logDoc.recycle();
                logDoc=null;
            }
            if (logDB!=null) {
                logDB.recycle();
                logDB=null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logStackTrace(e);
        }
    }

    public String doPost(String strObject){
        //do useful things
        log("useful post data")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if using Notes objects in a Serializable class as statics will work. If I need them that way I define them as transient. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Domino objects are **not** serializable.

You should use Domino objects **within** a class method only.

Store in class fields data like:

- Domino server's name,
- path to database,
- view's name,
- document's id or a list of documents' ids,
- document item's values,

This way you can easily get the Domino objects again when you need them.
But, never store Domino objects like session, database, view and document in class fields.
(Unless you instantiate the class at every request new and with it the fields - but this is definitely not the case when you use "static".)

Answer (score 1):

Backend objects retrieved via the provided sessions, like that, will be recycled at the end of each request. You should rewrite the class to re-retrieve the Document each request, either creating a new one each time or stashing the UNID of the doc when it’s created, and then using getDocumentByUNID.